# Error using Redux with React: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Just started learning redux and trying to make the simplest test app to work. This is the code and throws me that error in index.js line "ReactDOM.render("

My versions of React and ReactDOM are equal.

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Counter/counter.reducer.js:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { count: 0 };

const reducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    case "DECREMENT":
      return { ...state, count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Counter/counter.actions.js:

```
export const increaseCounter = () => {
  return { type: "INCREMENT" };
};

export const decreaseCounter = () => {
  return { type: "DECREMENT" };
};
```

App.js:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import React from "react";
import {
  increaseCounter,
  decreaseCounter,
} from "./redux/Counter/counter.actions";

function App({ count, increaseCounter, decreaseCounter }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Count:{count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => increaseCounter()}>Increase count</button>
      <button onClick={() => decreaseCounter()}>Decrease count</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { count: state.counter.count };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    increaseCounter: () => dispatch(increaseCounter()),
    decreaseCounter: () => dispatch(decreaseCounter()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: I've confirmed that [your code is fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-fast-i098g?file=/src/App.js), assuming that the `./redux/store` file is ok.  I would confirm that the versions of react and react-dom in your package.json match.  Then delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json.  Then run npm-install to install everything again to make sure that the version that's actually installed matches what's specified in your package.json.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Linda. I reinstalled everything from start and copied the files and it is working :) Before  I tried to delete node modules and package-log.json and run npm install but got an error. Why do you think it can be caused? and a way to solve?
 ERR! Found: @babel/core@7.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/core
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"7.12.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts

Comment: Sometimes I get errors like that if I installed a version of @babel/core that’s different than the version which react-scripts is expecting.